# MySQL Join table export to CSV with HTML body column

Tags: mysql

I've got below query to export to CSV with column body that has HTML values.

Problem is even though when I replace comma with space, it doesn't show up properly (as in not appearing correctly) and also rows are not terminating with line break.

```
SELECT j.id,j.title,j.featured,REPLCAE(j.body,',',' '),j.created,j.created_by,j.start_date,j.end_date,j.apply_link,o.name,o.website,o.logo,o.created,p.code,p.suburb,s.name INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/careersandjobs.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM job j
LEFT JOIN portfolio_job pj
ON pj.job_id = j.id
LEFT JOIN organisation o
ON o.id = j.organisation_id
LEFT JOIN postcode p
ON p.id = j.postcode_id
LEFT JOIN state s
ON s.id = p.state_id
WHERE published = 1
AND end_date > CURDATE()
AND pj.port_id = 8
```

Is there a reason behind this?

@Michael

I've tried with what you suggested but it now generates this error:

```
Failed to execute SQL : SQL SELECT j.id,j.title,j.featured,REPLACE(j.body,',',' ') as body,j.created,j.created_by,j.start_date,j.end_date,j.apply_link,o.name,o.website,o.logo,o.created,p.code,p.suburb,s.name INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/careersandjobs.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" FROM job j LEFT JOIN portfolio_job pj ON pj.job_id = j.id LEFT JOIN organisation o ON o.id = j.organisation_id LEFT JOIN postcode p ON p.id = j.postcode_id LEFT JOIN state s ON s.id = p.state_id WHERE published = 1 AND end_date > CURDATE() AND pj.port_id = 8 failed : Field separator argument is not what is expected; check the manual
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos: `SELECT j.id,j.title,j.featured,REPLCAE(j.body,',',' '),j.created,j.created_by,j.start_date,j.end_date,j.apply_link,o.name,o.website,o.logo,o.created,p.code,p.suburb,s.name INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/careersandjobs.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`

you have REPLCAE instead of REPLACE

Comment: I am sorry - please try it with your '\n' again, I made a mistake - I apologize.